# move div with sound file

Tags: javascript, audio

Using javascript I want to move a div depending on the sound channel volume, so say if a song is playing, the div will move up and down to a certain frequency of sound, so i could move one div to drums, another div to guitar and another to vocals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such API. You'll probably have to time your movements manually according to the song you play.